# LG Stylus 2 Wipe cache partition

Tags: recovery-mode, lg, cache

My friend have LG Stylus 2 quite laggy and need to wipe phone cache

We have already wipe cache from apps with following method

1. Drag down the notification bar and tap the Settings icon Settings icon.png at the top-right.
2. Tap General > Storage. (If using List view, scroll down to 'DEVICE' and tap Storage.
3. Wait for menu options to finish calculating.
4. Tap Cached data, then tap YES.
5. Wait for the cached data to clear; depending on size it will take several seconds to complete.
6. When the wipe is complete, the storage screen refreshes and cached data will not be listed. This means your our cached data has been successfully cleared.

and now we have tried the following method

1. Power off your device.
2. Wait a few seconds
3. Boot in recovery mode by pressing the Volume Down and Power Button at the same time for 2-3 seconds until the LG logo appears on the screen.
4. Release the buttons and press them again until the Recovery Screen appears

But the option is only factory data reset/wipe all data

How can I access the recovery mode for just wipe cache partition, like other phones like Samsung, Oppo, Asus, etc.?

Any help appreciated

Comment: All devices don't offer the option to wipe cache from built in recovery

Comment: If you have root access you may wipe cache manually. But as often as it is, you should never need to wipe cache alone without wiping data.

Comment: I had same issue in LG Stylus 2 - I had issue with "Unfortunately, the Process Com.android.phone has stopped".Please some one suggest solution, I need to backup my data anyhow, some images.